# Loading SchemaUrl takes too long in Java (XSD Validation)

Tags: xml, xsd, java-7, ubuntu-16.04, w3c

I am trying to validate an XML file against an xsd using the following Java code running in Java 7.0_80 and Tomcat 7 WebServer under an Ubuntu 16.04 operating system:

```
 SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
 Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaUrl);
 Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
 validator.validate(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml)));
```

The following instruction takes too long to respond:

> Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaUrl);

After several tries, Tomcat throws a JavaOutOfSpace error.

I had been working with this xsd file for a very long time, and the code actually works perfectly fine in another server with the same characteristics. This used to work perfectly in this server until we installed the security updates on 29/07/2017. Since then, we have tried the following:

- Uninstalled the security updates
- Install from scratch a new ubuntu server with same characteristics as server that is actually working
- Access locally the xsd file /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/AppName/schema.xsd and through http://localhost:8080/AppName/schema.xsd

The xsd file has some imports that are located locally, it doesnt have any imports outside the server: 
[image: Xsd declaration]

What I have read is that somethimes the problem might come when loading the DTDs of the W3C that are loaded in this declaration:

> xmlns:xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

The solution I had read is to load the DTD locally, the questions here are:

- What exactly should I load locally?
- How can I make reference to it locally in my xsd file?
- How can I update it every 60/90 days?
- Why I have this problem only in several servers due to the updates and not in my other servers?

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Incidental comment: Glad to see you’re loading the DTD locally. Tools that repeatedly try to fetch DTDs from the W3C site are broken and should be fixed and if they aren’t they’re going to run into rate limiting we have set up to discourage and block abuse. See https://www.w3.org/blog/systeam/2008/02/08/w3c_s_excessive_dtd_traffic/ for more details.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Do you know how can I load DTD locally and fetch them from the xsd?

Comment: I don’t know how to get the XSD processing code to load the schema locally but anyway a “JavaOutOfSpace” sounds like your Tomcat is causing Java to run out of heap space. It seems like you need to try increasing the heap space, which I think you can do by putting `export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms1g -Xmx1g" in your `catalina.sh` (with whatever value is appropriate in for you environment in place of the `1g`)

Comment: Ok thanks for that. The only reference I have to the w3c website is the declaration in the xsd header: xmlns:xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema". Does that instruction fetches the DTD everytime it tries to load the schema?

Comment: that `xmlns:xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` declaration on its own should not cause a DTD to be fetched as far as I know

Comment: Yeah, the problem appears to be that Java is running out of memory. You can try giving it more memory by doing what I described above, and that might fix the problem or it might not. If not they you’re gonna to figure out what changed that’s now causing it to require more heap space than it needed previously.